# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined react

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando filtrar los datos que traigo desde una API que guardo en una variable de estado llamada user, pero cuando intento usar la propiedad filter de la siguiente manera

```
let suscriptores=user.filter(Subscribed=>Subscribed==="yes")
console.log(suscriptores)
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

¿Cual podria ser el problema al querer filtrar los datos?

Llamado de los datos:

```
const url='/api/users';
const[user, setuser]= useState();

useEffect(()=>{
    const getUsers=async()=>{

            const response =await axios.get(url);
            setuser(response.data.data.datos);

    }
    getUsers();
},[]);
```

json

```
"data":{
    "datos": [
            {
                "id":1,
                "Name":"Alissa",
                "Age": 45,
                "Adress": "Brooklyn 405",
                "Phone": "212-324-4153",
        "Subscribed":"yes"
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "Name":"Ellis",
                "Age": 23,
                "Adress": "Boston 955",
                "Phone": "212-324-4152",
        "Subscribed":"yes"
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "Name":"Martha",
                "Age": 21,
                "Adress": "Boston 955",
                "Phone": "212-324-4152",
                "Subscribed":"no"
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: El error está claro, tu variable `user` está undefined. Yo imprimiría `response.data.data.datos` para ver qué valor tiene porque tiene pinta de que esa última propiedad `.datos` no existe en `response.data.data`.


Otro posible problema es que estás inicializando `user` sin valor inicial (undefined) -> `const[user, setuser]= useState();`. Si inicializas la variable con array vacío con`const[user, setuser]= useState([]);` estarás metiendo un santity check para evitarte este tipo de problemas

Comment: Si imprimo response.data.data.datos si me muestra los datos response.data.data.datos [{...},{...},{...}]

Comment: En donde estas aplicando `filter`? En otro componente? Donde está ubicada la variable `suscriptores`?

Comment: Si todo esta dentro del mismo componente

Comment: Prueba a inicializar el useState con array vacío

Comment: Ya no me muestra el error pero me arroja un array vacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema, es que el request hacia una API es asíncrono por naturaleza. Siempre hay una demora hasta que la información relevante es recuperada.

Y como `users` es null hasta que el request de API termina, la función `filter` queda `undefined`.

Para evitar esto, podemos usar `&&` para ejecutar la función filter cuando `users` tenga la información relevante.

Ademas, a la función `filter` le está faltando acceder a la propiedad relevante (vos definiste el parámetro como `Subscribed` cuando eso es la propiedad en cuestión que quieres verificar).

Y por último usamos [renderizado condicional](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) para mostrar la información relevante:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState(null);
  
  const suscriptores = users && users.filter(u => u.Subscribed === 'yes')
  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    simulateAPI.then((d) => {
      setUsers(d.data.datos);
    });
  }, []);
      
  return (
    <div>
      {!suscriptores ? (
        <p>Cargando..</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Suscriptores: {JSON.stringify(suscriptores)}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

// Simulamos el comportamiento de un API request
const json = {
  data: {
    datos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        Name: "Alissa",
        Age: 45,
        Address: "Brooklyn 405",
        Phone: "212-324-4153",
        Subscribed: "yes"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        Name: "Ellis",
        Age: 23,
        Address: "Boston 955",
        Phone: "212-324-4152",
        Subscribed: "yes"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        Name: "Martha",
        Age: 21,
        Address: "Boston 955",
        Phone: "212-324-4152",
        Subscribed: "no"
      }
    ]
  }
};



const simulateAPI = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(json);
  }, 1500);
});
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```